# find optimal sum of elements in list of numbers that are > a given number

Tags: algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming

I have a list of numbers, sorted descending, size of array is variable and any number can appear (typically less than 1000)

given an input number (x), I need to find the optimal combination of values in the list, that is larger than x by the smallest amount possible. I've been reading about the NP-optimization and sum subset type problems, but haven't found a solution yet. I've found some psuedocode for an approximate alogorithm, but i would like to find the exact optimal solution from the given list of numbers.
thanks

Comment: Are the numbers integers and/or signed?

Comment: @trincot - just integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments I understood that the input array has unsigned (integers).

This problem seems not much different from the [subset sum problem with non-negative integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Polynomial_time_approximate_algorithm) which can be solved in polynomial time.

I found this to be a reasonably well-performing algorithm that finds the optimal solution:

#### The algorithm in pseudo code

```
For each element of the array:
    select this element  
    if sum of selected <= x:
        # Sum is too small, so add more (smaller) term(s)
        execute algorithm recursively for the remaining part of array
    else if < sum in best solution so far:
        # Sum is closer to target, so this is currently the best
        best solution = current selected terms
    # Back-track: remove this term from the sum
    unselect this element
return best solutiuon
```

When the algorithm is called recursively the previous selected terms remain selected, and in the loop one more term is selected. It can recurse again, etc. The total number of selected terms corresponds to the depth of the recursion.

There are two ways in which the recursion cuts many combinations:

- when a high value term is selected, the remaining value for crossing the target value becomes relatively small, reducing the possibilities of which other terms can contribute to a (better) solution;
- when a lower value term is selected, the remaining number of terms is relatively small (because of the order), and so also the possibilities are reduced.

This suggests that the time complexity is less than *O(2<sup>n</sup>)*, which would be the complexity when all possible combinations would have to be investigated (or a constant fraction of it).

#### Implementation

Here is an implementation in JavaScript, so you can run it. It offers a randomize button so you can generate an array of any given length with random numbers, and a random target value.

The algorithm *seems* to run in the order of *O(n.logn)* time, by just looking at the number of combinations it checks on average. That is of course not a proof.

The comments in the code should give clarification.

```js
// Main  algorithm
function solve(a /* array of int */, x /* int */) {
    // Initialise
    var best = {sum: a[0] * a.length, numSumsVerified: 0, numTerms: 0, terms: []};
    var current = {sum: 0, terms: []};

    function recurse(start) {
        var ok = start < a.length;
        for (var i = start; i < a.length && best.sum > x + 1 && ok; i++) {
            // Use this term for the sum
            current.sum += current.terms[current.terms.length] = a[i];
            // Keep statistics of how many combinations we check
            best.numSumsVerified++;
            if (current.sum <= x) {
                // Sum is too small, so add more (smaller) term(s)
                ok = recurse(i+1);
            } else if (current.sum < best.sum) {
                // Sum is closer to target, so this is currently the best
                best.sum = current.sum;
                best.terms = current.terms.slice(0);
            }
            // Back-track: remove this term from the sum
            current.sum -= current.terms.pop();
        }
        return ok || i > start + 1;
    }

    // start the search, and capture errors
    try {
        recurse(0);
    } catch (ex) {
        best.error = 'Too much recursion!';
        best.sum = null;
        return best;
    }
    best.numTerms = best.terms.length;
    // if no solution, set error message
    if (!best.terms.length) {
        best.error = 'no solution';
        best.sum = null;
    }
    return best;
}

// Utility for randomizing
function createRandomNumbers(limit, count) {
    res = [];
    while (count--) res.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * limit));
    return res;
}

// I/O

var inputA = document.querySelector('#a');
var inputX = document.querySelector('#x');
var buttonSolve = document.querySelector('#solve');
var inputSize = document.querySelector('#size');
var buttonRandom = document.querySelector('#randomize');
var output = document.querySelector('pre');

buttonSolve.onclick = function() {
    // Get input
    var a = inputA.value.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
    var x = Number(inputX.value);
    // Sort descending
    a.sort(function(a,b) { return b-a; });
    // Solve
    var result = solve(a, x);
    // Output
    inputA.value = a.join(' '); // just for reformatting
        // Reduce detail when many items
    if (result.terms.length > 100) result.terms = '(too many to display)';
    output.textContent = JSON.stringify(result, null, 4);
};

buttonRandom.onclick = function() {
    // Generate random input
    var size = Number(inputSize.value);
    var limit = size * 20;
    var a = createRandomNumbers(limit, size).sort((a,b) => b-a);
    var sum = a.reduce((a,b) => a+b);
    var x = createRandomNumbers(sum, 1).pop();
    // Populate the input boxes
    inputA.value = a.join(' ');
    inputX.value = x;
    // Trigger click on "solve" button
    setTimeout(buttonSolve.click.bind(buttonSolve), 0);
}
```

```html
Enter list of integers: <input id="a" size="50" value="18 13 12 10 9 8 6 6 1 0"><br>
Sum must be larger than: <input id="x" size="10" value="16"><br>
<button id="solve">Solve</button><br>
Desired array size: <input id="size" size="6" value="50">
<button id="randomize">Random Input</button>
<pre></pre>
```

As this algorithm performs a recursive call for every term that is added to the combination, the recursion might go deep for large input arrays. At a certain point it may hit stack limits. In my browser that limit gets hit often near array sizes of 10,000 elements. Probably this algorithm can be rewritten without use of recursion if it needs to be used for such large arrays.

Comment: thanks, this looks pretty good. I am working with Java but I don't think it should be too hard to do something like this. i hope....

Comment: I made some updates. The condition I had to decide there was no solution, was wrong. Corrected now. At the same time you can now specify the size of the randomized array. You'll see that even for arrays of 1000 numbers, this runs in an acceptable time.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very much like a [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). If it is, then finding an exact solution is not going to be easy.

Why is that? It is because the best solution may be comprised of potentially any subset for your numbers. There are 2^N subsets, so that is an extremely large space to search for solutions.

How large is it?

```
Items | Search Space          | How this feels
16    | 65,536                | I can do it!
32    | 4,294,967,296         | Better go get lunch
40    | 1,099,511,627,776     | If I only had a supercomputer
50    | 1,125,899,906,842,624 | I will watch as the last stars day
```

There are tricks and things which can reduce the search space, but you'll still hit epicly large problems for low item counts.

Given this, you should:

1. Choose only small problem sizes and use exhaustive search because it is easy to implement.
2. Learn about branch-and-bound and other search space reducing techniques
3. Approximate. Everyone does it.

Comment: this is a knapsack problem I think..any suggestions on how to implement exhaustive search or a good way to approximate? "close enough" will suffice for what I am trying to do. thanks!

Comment: I don't agree it is a problem with complexity *2^N*.

Comment: yeah, I think you are correct. my apologies, I think I've been overthinking this

Comment: @trincot: That's nice. And meaningless. Why don't you provide an argument for why it's not? I see you've posted some black box code; what time complexity does it have?

Comment: @Richard, see my updated answer for some answers to that, although I have no proof for what the time complexity is of my algorithm. But your answer seems to indicate that an algorithm will run into problems with an input of 50 elements,  but my suggested algorithm runs fine on arrays with 1000 elements, and the statistics of the number of verified sums does not follow a `2^N` pattern at all. I did not notice any *"epically large problems for low item counts"*.

Comment: @trincot: Though you have no proof for your time complexity, you seem very confident that your algorithm is fast. If you do not see epically large problems perhaps it is because you are looking in the wrong places (biased inputs). Or perhaps I am wrong and this is not really the knapsack problem. Which do you think is the case?

Comment: I think this problem is not as complex as the knapsack problem, but more like the subset sum problem with non-negative integers. That the numbers are non-negative is a crucial condition, but it is what I understood is the case here. It makes the problem solvable in [polynomial time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Polynomial_time_approximate_algorithm). This is no claim that my algorithm is optimal though.

Comment: But, according to Garey and Johnson's "Computers and Intractibility" the subset sum problem with non-negative integers reduces to the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) ([screenshoot](https://imgur.com/5UZgeaS)), which is NP-complete and, therefore, as hard as knapsack. The problem is solvable in [pseudo-polynomial time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time), not polynomial time. Therefore, your algorithm cannot be polynomial for a general inputs. It has a _O(2^N)_ worst-case.

Comment: Tell you what, if you post a question to StackOverflow or cstheory.stackexchange.com with your algorithm asking why it runs in polynomial time when it shouldn't, I will explain in detail what's going on.